# How to determine sampling rate of a lock-in amplifier?

Tags: sampling, sensor, measurement

I am trying to figure out the sampling rate of a lock-in amplifier and how it is related to the time constant. For example, imagine measuring sinusoidal waves at $1$, $5$, $10$, and $50$ Hz frequencies with time constants of $30$, $10$, $3$, and $1$ seconds. The lock-in amplifier is used to measure the amplitudes and phases of these signals.

What is the sampling rate at each of these frequencies given the respective time constants? I know it is related to the low-pass filter at $3$ dB.

For context, the time constant is one of the inputs to the amplifier defined as $1/2\pi f$ where $f$ is the $-3$ dB frequency of the filter in the Stanford Research SR850 manual.

Comment: The classical lock-in amplifier is a continuous-time system, i.e. there's no sampling rate involved. However, if you digitize the signal you can of course lock onto a carrier wave numerically. However, realistically, you would drastically oversample such low signal frequencies. (I'm not quite sure what a "time constant" in this context is?) So, think in the kHz for sampling rates – just because you can use that oversampling for noise shaping, and such low rates are basically "free".

Comment: Thank you @Marcus Müller. I added a bit more text for the context you were missing (also defined the "time constant" as it appears in the manual). Given the new information, it is still no sampling rate involved?

Comment: No; nothing even says this thing samples. Even if it did, all these filter bandwidths, specified by these time constants, would only give us a very rough idea of the minimum possible sampling rate - and as said, expect such a device to oversample hundred-, maybe thousandfold. Since the time constants are not directly inversely proportional to the carrier frequencies, this is very likely.

Comment: Do you mean the sampling rate required to Nyquist sample the output with a given time constant?  Your specific lock in amplifier does internally have a sampling rate (256 KHz), but it isn't too relevant aside from understanding how the device functions.